# Achieve pagination feature in Ajax/PHP/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to perform pagination feature. Until now, I manage to generate the feature according to the data number in my database.

I'm using MariaDB. The problem is that when I try to click on page 2, the parameter is got back well in the url : xxx.php?page=2, but data are not updated !

Page always displays the same data. No error is displayed in logs

```
<?php
require('config/config.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['flash']))
{
    foreach($_SESSION['flash'] as $type => $message)
    {
        echo $message;
    }
    unset($_SESSION['flash']);
}

$output = '';
$limit_per_page = 5;
$page = "";
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
    $query = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidacies WHERE lastName LIKE :lastName OR firstName LIKE :firstName OR age LIKE :age OR scheduleRange LIKE :scheduleRange OR phoneNumber LIKE :phoneNumber OR email LIKE :email OR candidacyType LIKE :candidacyType");
    $element = "%".$_POST['query']."%";
    $query->bindValue(':lastName', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':firstName', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':age', $element, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':scheduleRange', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':phoneNumber', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':email', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':candidacyType', $element, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
else if(isset($_POST['entries']))
{
    $entries = intval($_POST['entries']);
    $query = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidacies LIMIT :entries");
    $query->bindValue(':entries', $entries, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
else
{       
    $page = (!empty($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1);
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit_per_page;

    $query = $cnx->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM candidacies LIMIT :limit_per_page OFFSET :start");
    $query->bindValue(':limit_per_page', $limit_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $query->rowCount();

$resultFoundRows = $cnx->prepare('SELECT found_rows()');
$resultFoundRows->execute();
$listElements = $resultFoundRows->fetchColumn();

if($count > 0)
{
    $output .= '
        <table class="table table-striped" id="candidaciesTable">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">firstName</th>
                <th scope="col">lastName</th>
                <th scope="col">Âge</th>
                <th scope="col">Schedule Range</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Candidacy Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    ';
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {

        $output .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["firstName"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["lastName"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["age"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["scheduleRange"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["phoneNumber"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($value["email"])."</td>
                <td>".htmlspecialchars($search["candidacyType"])."</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class='btn btn-light btnViewCandidacy' id=".$value['id'].">
                            <i class='far fa-eye'></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class='btn btn-info' id='btnEditCandidacy' onclick='editCandidacy(".$value['id'].")'>
                            <i class='far fa-edit'></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger' id='btnDeleteCandidacy' onclick='deleteCandidacy(".$value['id'].")'>
                            <i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
    $output .= "
            </tbody>
        </table>";

    $output .= '
        <div class="pagination-centered">
            <ul>'
        ?>
        <?php 
            $numberPages = ceil($listElements / $limit_per_page);
            if($page > 1):
                $output .= '<a href="?page='. ($page - 1).'">Prev</a> —';
            endif;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberPages; $i++):
                $output .= '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
            endfor;
            if($page < $numberPages):
                $output .= '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next</a>';
            endif;
            $output .= '
            </ul>
        </div>';
    echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo '<div class="alert alert-info">No results found !</div>';
}
?>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     loadData();

     function loadData(query)
     {
         $.ajax({
             url:"search.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{query:query},
             success:function(data)
             {
                 $('#result').html(data);
             }
        });
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you posting the query? ```loadData()``` is called without any arguments, meaning the ```query``` variable will not contain any values. In other words, does ```isset($_POST['query'])``` evaluate to ```true``` and does ```$element``` contain any data?

Comment: Yeah, isset($_POST['query']) and isset($_POST['entries']) == true, but the code is not executed in my else condition. Furthermore, when I put var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_POST), that returns me empty array